# Connection String issues in WPF

Tags: sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, connection-string

I have just completed my first project in WPF using C# and MS SQL 2008 express. I have used Visual Studio 2010. What I have right now is a class `conn.cs' that has a method that returns me the connection string as and when I require. Also I just noticed that I have an App.Config file that also has a connection string defined there (both strings refer to the same database).

My `conn.cs`

```
class conn
    {
        public string get_connection()
        {
            string conn_string = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=msp;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            return conn_string;
        }
    }
```

App.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="msp.Properties.Settings.mspConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=msp;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to know two things now.

1. How can I fetch the Connection String from the App.Config? I need to do this then, I will fetch the string in my `conn.cs` from there, and then, I will just change the connection string in the app.config as and when required.
2. Also tell me, is it possible to set connection string at run time? I want the user to browse to the database `(.mdf)` file on First Run and then the connection string should get generated and saved in `app.config`. I can then easily pick it up from there and use.

Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get access your connection string using this:

```
string connString = Properties.Settings.Default.mspConnectionString;
```

(when typing Properties.Settings.Default you should automatically see your choices in the Member List)

You can of course set the connection string at runtime; it is basically just another string. I would not recommend hard-coding the connection string; though.

You might want to give the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class a try; see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-AT/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for example. But actually I never used it so far except for a few experiments here and there although I literally only do database-driven software...

Comment: I will give it a try and will post here soon.

Comment: Can I SET the ConnectionString in app.config at runtime? I guess the above code allows only getting.

Comment: Never tried that actually; as a ConnectionString is always an ApplicationSetting and not a UserSetting I do not think you can save it during runtime. But you could try creating a String UserSetting and use this for storing the connection string; these can be overwritten and saved.